# How to deal with with result of org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter.runForMultipleInputsOutputs()

Tags: java, android, arrays, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am running posenet (which is a CNN) on android with tflite.
The model has multiple output arrays with the following dimensions:
`1x14x14x17, 1x14x14x34, 1x14x14x32, 1x14x14x32`

Therefore running the java tflite interpreter with

```
import org.tensorflow.lite.Interpreter;
Interpreter tflite;
...
tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs,outputs)
```

i can access the four output tensors with `tflite.getOutputTensor(i)` or with `outputs.get(i)` (with i el. [0,3]) as `outputs` is a `HashMap` filled with `java.nio.HeapByteBuffer` objects.

How can I convert these outputs or tflite tensors to java multi-dimensional arrays (something like `float[][][][];`) to be able to perform mathematical computations on them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining the outputs like the following lets you work with native java arrays, which is what i wanted:

```
out1 = new float[1][14][14][17];
out2 = new float[1][14][14][34];
out3 = new float[1][14][14][32];
out4 = new float[1][14][14][32];
Map<Integer, Object> outputs = new HashMap<>();
outputs.put(0, out1);
outputs.put(1, out2);
outputs.put(2, out3);
outputs.put(3, out4);
```

Answer (score 4):

```java
// The shape of *1* output's tensor
int[] OutputShape;
// The type of the *1* output's tensor
DataType OutputDataType;
// The multi-tensor ready storage
outputProbabilityBuffers = new HashMap<>();

ByteBuffer x;
// For each model's tensors (there are getOutputTensorCount() of them for this tflite model)
for (int i = 0; i < tflite.getOutputTensorCount(); i++) {
    OutputShape = tflite.getOutputTensor(i).shape();
    OutputDataType = tflite.getOutputTensor(i).dataType();
    x = TensorBuffer.createFixedSize(OutputShape, OutputDataType).getBuffer();
    outputProbabilityBuffers.put(i, x);
    LOGGER.d("Created a buffer of %d bytes for tensor %d.", x.limit(), i);
}

LOGGER.d("Created a tflite output of %d output tensors.", outputProbabilityBuffers.size());
```

Example output:

```
Classifier: Created a buffer of 11264 bytes for tensor 0.
Classifier: Created a buffer of 11264 bytes for tensor 1.
Classifier: Created a buffer of 4 bytes for tensor 2.
Classifier: Created a buffer of 11264 bytes for tensor 3.
Classifier: Created a tflite output of 4 output tensors.
```

And use it that way:

```java
Object[] inputs = { your_regular_input };
tflite.runForMultipleInputsOutputs(inputs, outputProbabilityBuffers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Output: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/object_detection/overview#output

```
val locations = outputs.getValue(0).asFlowArray(),
val classes = outputs.getValue(1).asFlowArray(),
val scores = outputs.getValue(2).asFlowArray(),
val detections = outputs.getValue(3).asFlowArray()
```